# Max-Length for multiple text areas using php and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, maxlength

I am trying to display the number of characters left in multiple text areas. Although I have different ID's for the text areas, the max length is prompted only for the 2nd text area and not for the first. My code is as shown below

```
<textarea id="txtBox"></textarea> 
    <input type="text" id="counterBox"/>
        <script>
            var txtBoxRef = document.querySelector("#txtBox");
            var counterRef = document.querySelector("#counterBox");
            txtBoxRef.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
            var remLength = 0;
            remLength = 160 - parseInt(txtBoxRef.value.length);
            if(remLength < 0)
            {
                txtBoxRef.value = txtBoxRef.value.substring(0, 160);
                return false;
            }
            counterRef.value = remLength + " characters remaining...";
            },true);
        </script>

<textarea id="txtBox1"></textarea> 
    <input type="text" id="counterBox1"/>
            <script>
                var txtBoxRef = document.querySelector("#txtBox1");
                var counterRef = document.querySelector("#counterBox1");
                txtBoxRef.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
                var remLength = 0;
                remLength = 160 - parseInt(txtBoxRef.value.length);
                if(remLength < 0)
                {
                txtBoxRef.value = txtBoxRef.value.substring(0, 160);
                return false;
                }
                counterRef.value = remLength + " characters remaining...";
                },true);
            </script>
```

> **The result is as below (What I have):**

[image]

> **What I want :**

[image]

Comment: Some random comments: Why are you using an INPUT field to display output data? If you use `keydown` you'll miss typematic repeated keys; use `keypress` instead.  Notice 156+5 characters = 161, not 160.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the variables `txtBoxRef` and `counterRef` are in the same scope area, you declared twice.

```html
<textarea id="txtBox"></textarea> 
    <input type="text" id="counterBox"/>
        <script>
            var txtBoxRef = document.querySelector("#txtBox");
            var counterRef = document.querySelector("#counterBox");
            txtBoxRef.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
            var remLength = 0;
            remLength = 160 - parseInt(txtBoxRef.value.length);
            if(remLength < 0)
            {
                txtBoxRef.value = txtBoxRef.value.substring(0, 160);
                return false;
            }
            counterRef.value = remLength + " characters remaining...";
            },true);
        </script>

<textarea id="txtBox1"></textarea> 
    <input type="text" id="counterBox1"/>
            <script>
                var txtBoxRef1 = document.querySelector("#txtBox1");
                var counterRef1 = document.querySelector("#counterBox1");
                txtBoxRef1.addEventListener("keydown",function(){
                var remLength = 0;
                remLength = 160 - parseInt(txtBoxRef1.value.length);
                if(remLength < 0)
                {
                txtBoxRef1.value = txtBoxRef1.value.substring(0, 160);
                return false;
                }
                counterRef1.value = remLength + " characters remaining...";
                },true);
            </script>
```

check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sachinkk/tmcf33ro/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<textarea id="txtBox"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="counterBox"/>
<script>
    var txtBoxRef=document.querySelector("#txtBox");
    var counterRef=document.querySelector("#counterBox");
    txtBoxRef.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
        var remLength=0;
        remLength=160 - parseInt(txtBoxRef.value.length);
        if(remLength < 0){
            txtBoxRef.value=txtBoxRef.value.substring(0, 160);
            return false;
        }
        counterRef.value=remLength + " characters remaining...";
    }, true);
</script>
<textarea id="txtBox1"></textarea>
<input type="text" id="counterBox1"/>
<script>
    var txtBoxRef1=document.querySelector("#txtBox1");
    var counterRef1=document.querySelector("#counterBox1");
    txtBoxRef1.addEventListener("keyup", function(){
        var remLength=0;
        remLength=160 - parseInt(txtBoxRef1.value.length);
        if(remLength < 0){
            txtBoxRef1.value=txtBoxRef1.value.substring(0, 160);
            return false;
        }
        counterRef1.value=remLength + " characters remaining...";
    }, true);
</script>
```

> Your code can be optimized if you give it a thought.